# How to write a constructor function in TypeScript that has method extension functionality

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, typescript-typings

I want to write a constructor function that takes some predefined methods from an object (`Methods`) and injects it into every new object that is created with the constructor. It injects methods from another object because, I want the consumers of my module to be able to add new methods.
But the problem is: as all the injected methods are not defined in the constructor I can't seem to manage their type annotations properly.

It's hard for me to describe the problem so I created a simple example (*with JavaScript to avoid all the type error*) to demonstrate it.

```js
// methods.js ---------------------------------------
const methods = {};

const addMethod = (name, value) => (methods[name] = value);

// these methods should be added by an external user of the programmer.js module
function code(...task) {
  this.addInstruction({
    cmd: "code",
    args: task
  });
  return this;
}

function cry(...words) {
  this.addInstruction({
    cmd: "cry",
    args: words
  });
  return this;
}

addMethod("code", code);
addMethod("cry", cry);

// programmer.js -------------------------------------
const retriveInstructionsMethod = "SECRET_METHOD_NAME";
const secretKey = "VERY_SECRET_KEY";

function Programmer() {
  const instructions = [];
  this.addInstruction = (value) => instructions.push(value);

  Object.defineProperty(this, retriveInstructionsMethod, {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value(key) {
      if (key === secretKey) return instructions;
    },
  });

  for (const key of Object.keys(methods))
    this[key] = (...args) => methods[key].apply(this, args);
}

// test.js -------------------------------------------
const desperateProgrammer = new Programmer();

const instructions = desperateProgrammer
  .code("A library in typescript within 10 days")
  .cry("Oh God! Why everything is so complicated :'( ? Plz Help!!!")

// the next two lines shouldn't work here (test.js) as the user
// shouln't have asscess to the "retriveInstructionsMethod"  and "secretKey"
// keys.  I'm just showing it to demonstrate what I want to achieve.
[retriveInstructionsMethod](secretKey);
console.log(instructions);
```

Here I want to hide all the instructions given to a `Programmer` object. If I hide it from the end user then I won't have to validate those instructions before executing them later.

And the user of `programmer.js` module should be able to add new methods to a programmer. For example:

```js
// addMethods from "methods.js" module
addMethods("debug", (...bugs) => {...});
```

Now I know that, I can create a base class and just extend it every time I add a new method. But as it is expected that there will be lots of external methods so soon it will become very tedious for the user.

Below is what I've tried so far. But the type annotation clearly doesn't work with the following setup and I know it should not! Because the `Methods` interface's index signature(`[key: string]: Function`) is very generic and I don't know all the method's **name** and **signature** that will be added later.

`methods.ts`

```
export interface Methods {
  [key: string]: Function;
}

const methods: Methods = {};

export default function getMethods(): Methods {
  return { ...methods };
}

export function addMethods<T extends Function>(methodName: string, method: T) {
  methods[methodName] = method;
}
```

`programmer.ts`

```
import type { Methods } from "./methods";
import getMethods from "./methods";

export type I_Programmer = Methods & {
  addInstruction: (arg: { cmd: string; args: unknown[] }) => void;
};

interface ProgrammerConstructor {
  new (): I_Programmer;
  (): void;
}

const retriveInstructionsMethod = "SECRET_METHOD_NAME";
const secretKey = "ACCESS_KEY";

const Programmer = function (this: I_Programmer) {
  const instructions: object[] = [];
  this.addInstruction = (value) => instructions.push(value);

  Object.defineProperty(this, retriveInstructionsMethod, {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value(key: string) {
      if (key === secretKey) return instructions;
    },
  });

  const methods = getMethods();
  for (const key of Object.keys(methods))
    this[key] = (...args: unknown[]) => methods[key].apply(this, args);
} as ProgrammerConstructor;

// this function is just to demonstrate how I want to extract all the
// instructions. It should not be accessible to the end user.
export function getInstructionsFrom(programmer: I_Programmer): object[] {
  // gives error
  // @ts-expect-error
  return programmer[retriveInstructionsMethod][secretKey]();
}

export default Programmer;
```

`testUsages.ts`

```
import { addMethods } from "./methods";
import type { I_Programmer } from "./programmer";
import Programmer, { getInstructionsFrom } from "./programmer";

function code(this: I_Programmer, task: string, deadline: string) {
  this.addInstruction({ cmd: "code", args: [task, deadline] });
  return this;
}

function cry(this: I_Programmer, words: string) {
  this.addInstruction({ cmd: "cry", args: [words] });
  return this;
}

addMethods("code", code);
addMethods("cry", cry);

const desperateProgrammer = new Programmer()
  .code("a library with typescript", "10 days") // no type annotation of "code" method 
  .cry("Oh God! Why everything is so complicated :'( ? Plz Help!!!"); // same here

// Just for demonstration. Should not be accessible to the end user!!!
console.log(getInstructionsFrom(desperateProgrammer));
```

Kindly give me some hint how I can solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _If I hide it from the end user then I won't have to validate those instructions before executing them later._ -- Relying on this is dangerous. Best is yet to be _transparent_ and _perform proper validation_ at any point in your application/framework.

Comment: @jbndlr Thanks for your feedback. Actually those instructions will contain commands for another module to validate user input with predefined schemas. I want to hide those instruction so that  in case of an exploitation someone won't be able to change the data validation schema (those instructions). But if any instruction is invalid then the validator module will an throw error automatically. But hiding it is not that important as I can make it immutable. But the problem is with all the type annotation of all the methods  that will be added later :(